# CALLBACK ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, handlebars.js

I'm adding a pagination in my product list. But I kept having error:

```
console.log(data.rows);
                   ^
```

Here's my js file that's query-ing in my database:

```
list: (client, filter, callback) => {
const productListQuery = `
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY id
`;
client.query(productListQuery, (req, result)=>{
  console.log(result.rows);
  callback(result.rows);
});
```

Here's my router.get in my server.js:

```
app.get('/products', function (req, res, next) {
  Product.list(client, {limit: 8}, {offset: (req.query.p - 1) * 8}, {
  }, function (products) {
    res.render('/client/product-list', {
      products: products,
      title: 'Products',
      pagination: {
        page: req.query.p || 1,
        limit: 8,
        n: req.query.p || 1
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add your code :)

Comment: Please add your code as content to the question, not as image links.

Answer (score 2):

That just simply means your `data` is `undefined` and in JavaScript `undefined` objects don't have any property or value.

Would recommend you to go though [JavaScript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) before using it.

When you called your database, there was an error in response and since you didn't handled response correctly thus getting this error.

To understand different between `undefined` and other object values:

```
let a;
let b = 22;
let c = null;
let d = {
    'a': 22,
    'b': [4,5,6]
};

console.log(a);  // undefined
console.log(a.b);  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined
console.log(b);  // 22
console.log(b.c);  // undefined
console.log(c);  // null
console.log(d.a);  // 22
console.log(d.b);  // [4,5,6]
console.log(e);  // ReferenceError: e is not defined
```